# Intersection of a line and a line segment

Tags: geometry

How can I find if a line segment and a line intersect? The line segment is given by the points p1 and p2, and the line is given by the equation y=mx+b. The line and the line segment are co-planar, so this is for the 2D case.

I can only find solutions for intersection of two lines, or of two line segments.

Comment: All the points of the line segment are of the form $p=rp_1+(1-r)p_2$ for $r\in[0,1]$. Put this $p$ in $y=mx+b$ and check if there is a solution for such $r$. This allows you to find the intersection, if you need it.

Comment: If you are programming and only need to test the existence of the intersection, you can just evaluate $y-mx-b$ at the points $p_1,p_2$. If for one you get a positive number and for the other you get a negative value, then the segment crosses the line.

Comment: Doesn’t the algorithm for finding the intersection of two line segments essentially compute the intersection of the lines that contain the segments?

Comment: Yes, but they are not two line segments; one is a line.